# How can I rotate a visio 2010 page in 90 degrees without using the mouse that rotates inaccurately?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

How can I rotate a Visio 2010 page 90° without using the mouse?

Using the mouse takes too long and is inaccurate.

Comment: While not purely rotating the page, the Re-Layout page will change the angle of the entire page including re-flowing from top to bottom to right to left. Which is Alt->desi(G)n->(R)e-Layout Page. Are you trying to rotate the page(portrait->Landscape) to fit the shapes, or the shapes to fit the page?

Answer (score -1):

Click on the shape to be rotated:

On the "Home" tab select Position → Rotate Shapes → (Rotate Left or Rotate)

Comment: That rotates the shape(s) on the page, not the page itself - very different.

Comment: This seems to be gone in visio 2016 :(, and no matter what combination of Ctrl, Alt or Shift i press it just rotates on free hand..
but this worked -> http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/jan/28/rotating-visio-shapes-arbitrary-degree/